# Django - form fields attributes for logged user

Tags: django, django-authentication

I would like to add readonly attribute to one of form fields. This is a part of my forms.py file:

```
class SiteAddFormFull(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SiteAddFormFull, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['group'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Group.objects.filter(is_active=True), initial='Podstawowy',
            help_text="<div id='group'><ul><li>Sample text</b></li></ul></div>",
            label="Rodzaj wpisu")

    url = forms.URLField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),
                     label='Adres internetowy')
    kod = forms.CharField(label="Kod premium", required=False)
    user = forms.CharField(label="Nazwa użytkownika", 
widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
    if user_is_authenticated:
        email = forms.EmailField(label="Email adress", 
widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'min-width:30%'}))
```

I would like to add readonly attribute to email field. I don't have any idea how could I use authentication system here. What should I put instead of user_is_authenticaded? Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I added:

```
email = self['email'].value()

if email is not None:
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'readonly': 'readonly'})
```

below `super(SiteAddFormFull, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Every user has email field. It works fine. One hour of trials and errors... It is solved. Thanks.